# select random rows seed in sql server

Tags: sql-server, random

I am trying to select random rows in Sql Server using a seed.
I a,m aware of the function `newid()`, however I couldn't find a way to use a seed with this function.
I want to run a code such as:

```
select user_id from users;
go
```

The code above selects users not in a random manner, I need assistance to in changing it to select users randomly according to a seed. So that if I run the same select with the same seed, I will get the same users.

Thanks,
Clint

Comment: The only safe way to do it (that I'm aware of) is to add a new column that contains the random numbers that you generate on one pass over the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx) that would select number between 0 to 99 and approximately top 10 percent:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE (ABS(CAST(
(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10
```

So, if you want 0 to 19 then use 20 instead of 100 for example.

I have not so elegant solution but worth the try like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, user_name, RandVal  FROM (
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(CAST(RAND(user_id)*100 as varchar(100)),3) as int) as RandVal,    user_id, user_name
FROM users) T
WHERE RandVal BETWEEN 700 and 900
```

See my [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/929a7/2)

I used `user_id` as the **seed**.

And this one also:

```
SELECT TOP 5 user_id, MAX(user_name), MAX(RandVal) as RandVal FROM (
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(CAST(RAND(user_id)*100 as varchar(100)),2) as int) as RandVal,     user_id, user_name
FROM users) T
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY RandVal
```

See my [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/929a7/6) for this one also.

Comment: Thanks ... but where do I specify the seed ?
My purpose is to run the select twice and get the same random numbers.

Comment: @user502490 - you would pass it inside `RAND(<here>)` - but note that this now depends on nothing changing in the table at all, and even then I'm not sure that it's 100% reliable.

Comment: You could put value inside the RAND() function like RAND(100).

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get 10 random users:

```
SELECT user_id From users WHERE rand()>0.5 limit 10;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I miss "same feed - same users" condition

Comment: This is not in Sql-Server:(

Comment: I think need write "MSSql server" here... MySql server is Sql-server too)