# Order By VarBinary expression not sorted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, varbinary, newid

While attempting to [generate a seeded random ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17269389/256431) I noted this issue, now replicated both in SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) and on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162572/testing-sub-select-order-failure?opt.textResults=true&opt.withExecutionPlan=true#messages), i.e. SQL Server 2012 (SP1):

When you `ORDER BY` a `VarBinary` sub-`SELECT` field the ordering does not occur.

In the query plan (of SEDE above) you can see that there is no SORT for:

```
SELECT [id]
  ,y.x As ryx
  ,RAND(y.x) As yx
FROM #Test, (SELECT CONVERT(varbinary, NEWID()) As x) y
ORDER BY ryx
```

where as there is for all the other variations I tried (and you can see them in the SEDE query, as well as if you edit them to `ORDER BY yx`).

I've had a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx) and only confirmed `VarBinary` use [MACHINE collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swbw1ewb.aspx) when indexed.

Is this just a bug or a poorly documented feature? :-)

Comment: The issue is depend on `NEWID()` not on `varbianry`. But it is must be fixed in 2012.

Comment: It may be related to `NEWID` being capable of being non-deterministic, but you can see from the successfully sorting alternatives that `VarBinary` has something to do with it. (Tag added nevertheless.)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan It is definitely not fixed in 2012: you can see the query plans on SEDE.

Comment: Try to move the subquery from `from`clause to `select`. See this: SELECT b.a
  ,b.x As ryx
  ,RAND(b.x) As yx
FROM
(SELECT x.a, 
  (SELECT CONVERT(varbinary, NEWID()) As x) x
FROM (values (1), (1), (1), (2), (5), (1), (6)) as x(a)) b
ORDER BY ryx

Comment: Look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28883

Comment: Thanks for the workarounds. I note a few myself in the SEDE query. I'm looking for confirmation this is just a bug.

Comment: newid() is buggy. This is bug i found on far 2005 year. `select a from 
(select abs(checksum(newid())%10) a from sysobjects) b group by a order by 1` This was return repeating value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug.

```
Create Table #Test(Id Int NOT NULL)
 INSERT Into #Test VALUES(1)
 INSERT Into #Test VALUES(2)

SELECT @@VERSION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [id]
        ,y.x As ryx
        ,RAND(y.x) As yx
    FROM #Test, (SELECT CONVERT(varbinary,NEWID()) As x) y
) x
ORDER BY ryx --order by outside!
```

See https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162636/testing-sub-select-order-failure?opt.textResults=true&opt.withExecutionPlan=true

Example results:

```
id          ryx
----------- -----------------------------------
1           0xC15FAED68C9A134882A2C977C46F1B8D --wrong order
2           0x532169D935535543BE0E0B24CA5D04FB --wrong order
```

In this query the `order by` is clearly on the outside. It should not matter in what way the derived table `x` is generated. The `order by` must apply. The rows are returned in unsorted order.

Report it to Microsoft Connect. It is an optimizer bug.

Comment: Note that you _don't_ actually just get one evaluation multiple times, but it may be the query plan thought that was the case.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. I just tried this on SEDE (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162627/testing-sub-select-order-failure). This particular way of writing the query forces a correct query plan.

Comment: I was referring to my original query that is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

On the way to adding this to Connect, I [note](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/618303/optimizer-moving-computer-scalar-yields-unexpected-result) `NEWID()` is dangerous in expressions, as it *is* "by design" that expressions are re-evaluated every time they're accessed, not just once per "local" row.

This is further discussed [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions), where it is explained the designers of SQL Server decided to go with optimisation over accuracy (the opposite of most programming language compilers).

So, before I see an actual result from my [Connect submission](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/814672/varbinary-newid-is-not-sorted), I'm guessing this is the result of slightly over-optimising when the conversion to VarBinary is in the "wrong" place.

Specifically, this [works](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/162853/207609/testing-sub-select-order-failure#executionPlan):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT [id]
    ,CONVERT(varbinary,y.x) As ryx
    ,RAND(CONVERT(varbinary,y.x)) As yx
  FROM #Test, (SELECT NEWID() As x) y
)x
ORDER BY ryx
```

where as [usr's query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162636/testing-sub-select-order-failure?opt.textResults=true&opt.withExecutionPlan=true#executionPlan) in his answer doesn't.

Comment: If you look at my previous answer (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21331107/revisions) you'll see that I also mentioned this. Unfortunately, the question is not about fixing this issue as I later noticed :( I think my answer proves that it is a bug though. The only question is whether it will be recognized by the team as such.

Comment: @usr You may note I used your outer `SELECT ... ORDER BY` formulation in the bug report.

Comment: The result of my Connect submission is "won't fix".